# react js useState array is empty in first time click in the console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please check my below code. I try to check the console log value, but in the first button click, the array is empty. After the second click the array will be loaded correctly.

Please check this:

[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-with-array-hduec?from-embed=&file=/src/HookWithArray.js)

The above sample can be found on Google. I console log the value as below
[image]

Why is the array empty in the first click? Another question is, I need to print the value in the first click. How can I do it? Do you know any alternative method?

Comment: `items` isn't empty *on first click*, but *on first render*. Which is reasonable as your initial state is an empty array (`useState([]);`).

Comment: When I run the sandbox, the empty array appears before the first click. This is expected behavior. Also keep in mind that state setters are async; depending on where you're logging state, you will get the old value.

Comment: @ChrisG Even if the updater were fully synchronous, they could not update the current state variable.

Comment: it's not empty on first click actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not empty on the first click but you can handle it this way :

```
const addItem = () => {
    setItem([
      ...items,
      {
        id: items.length,
        value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
      }
    ]);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items);
  }, [items]);
```

The useEffect hook will console log items after they've been changed so you will see the latest state or in other words the updated and final state .